# Failed to execute 'removeChild'

Tags: javascript

```js
var first_content = document.getElementById('first-content'),
 offered_games = document.getElementById('offered-games');

for(var i = 0, e = offered_games.children; i < e.length; i++) {
  e[i].onmouseenter = function() {
    // img_player.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.children[0].children[0].src + ')';
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.children[0].children[0].src;
    img.classList.add('added-promotion');
    first_content.appendChild(img);
    setTimeout(function() {
      img.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 10)
  }

  function removeImg(img) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      first_content.removeChild(img)
    }, 300) 
  }

  e[i].onmouseleave = function() {
    var added_promo = document.querySelectorAll('.added-promotion') || document.querySelector('.added-promotion');

    for(var i = 0, e = added_promo; i < e.length; i++) {
      e[i].style.opacity = 0;

      removeImg(e[i])
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.first-content .img#img-player {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.first-content #offered-games {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 980px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  bottom: 180px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -490px;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 235px;
  margin-left: 9.3px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game:hover .top {
  height: 100px;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game:hover .top img {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-30px) scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-30px) scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: translateY(-30px) scale(1.2);
  transform: translateY(-30px) scale(1.2);
}

.first-content #offered-games .game:hover .bottom .text {
  max-height: 235px;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game:hover .bottom .text p.content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.sportsbook .top {
  border-top: 4px solid #ff0039;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.sportsbook .bottom p.title {
  color: #ff0039;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.sportsbook .bottom button {
  background: #ff0039;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.poker .top {
  border-top: 4px solid #0c82b1;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.poker .bottom p.title {
  color: #0c82b1;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.poker .bottom button {
  background: #0c82b1;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.casino .top {
  border-top: 4px solid #efb717;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.casino .bottom p.title {
  color: #efb717;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.casino .bottom button {
  background: #efb717;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.bolatangkas .top {
  border-top: 4px solid #0db561;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.bolatangkas .bottom p.title {
  color: #0db561;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game.bolatangkas .bottom button {
  background: #0db561;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .top {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .top img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .bottom {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .bottom .text {
  max-height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .bottom .text.active {
  max-height: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .bottom .text p.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .bottom .text p.content {
  margin: 8px 0 5px;
  color: #6b6b6b;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: justify;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.first-content #offered-games .game .bottom button.btn-view {
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-content" class="first-content">
  <div id="img-player" class="img"></div>
  <div id="offered-games">
    <div data-info="sportsbook" class="game sportsbook">
      <div class="top"><img src="http://0.tqn.com/d/worldsoccer/1/L/u/M/-/-/451274454.jpg"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="text">
          <p class="title">Game 1</p>
          <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-info="poker" class="game poker">
      <div class="top"><img src="http://cache4.asset-cache.net/gc/492689397-soccer-player-standing-on-pitch-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=%2F7DaYEj3tOfsAmZVQjUjN%2Fp85xL5t%2FRvXvNDXWwcD%2BWLs1oLsXFGW8D%2BBw37QVMl96M1ZTHpoFW9f6CnK92rTg%3D%3D"></div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="text">
          <p class="title">Game 2</p>
          <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

When you hover extremely fast I get that error. But if hover slow. It works well.

Why I keep getting this error? Actually it's working but I think it can affect the template that I am proposing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Glanced at this, saw a wall of code, and turned away. Consider editing to provide more of a [_Minimal_, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @qxz Actually it is minimize since I provided code snippet that's running. I removed all unneccessary code. Maybe I make it two selections only. Thanks

Comment: The error seems quite clear, you're trying to remove an element from another element that isn't the first elements direct parent. Console log the elements, and figure out what elements you've got.

Comment: Also, if `querySelectorAll` doesn't return any elements, surely `querySelector` with the same selector won't return anything either ?

Comment: change `first_content.removeChild(img)` to `img.remove()` - then you don't need to worry about having the right parent ... if the browser you are using doesn't have the remove method, `img.parentNode.removeChild(img)`

Comment: Why set a timeout to 300  when you `removeImg`?

Comment: My guess is that your timeout of 300 will let `removeImg` be called twice before the element is actually removed. Maybe add a check to see if it's already been removed?

Comment: @Searching for animation.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks. It worked. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `first_content.removeChild(img)` to `img.remove()` - then you don't need to worry about having the right parent ... if the browser you are using doesn't have the remove method, `img.parentNode.removeChild(img)`